# Determinate perimeter and area of an n-angle in c++

Tags: geometry, programming

Okay, so this is what the textbook says:
"The user will input n points in $R^2$, the program needs to determine wether or not this is a n-angle polygon and if so calculate the area and perimeter of such a figure".

To determine wether or not this is a n-angle polygon is rather easy, I made a point and a vector class, the program takes the first point and then forms n-1 vectors, if any of this vectors is parallel or antiparallel with any other, well it's not an n-angle polygon, otherwise it is, so far so good.

Now for the real problem, you need to determine which points form amongst them a side, to determine the perimiter and area, but this program is suppoused to work with any type of polygon, wether regular or not.

Is there any efficient way that actually works to know how two points form a side and not a diagonal? Having this I could use Gauss' formula or even Heron's.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is an n angle polygon?

Comment: I guess n-angle polygon just means n-gon (i.e. $n$ sides, $n$ interior angles). Your check is alarming to me! Even a square has two pairs of parallel sides.

Comment: @copper.hat, yes it's a n-gon.

Comment: @preferred_anon, remember that it's a point with the other 3, no just any 3 vectors, so it's not an issue.

Comment: @JocsanArielHernandezBarahon Sorry! I misunderstood. I don't think that the perimeter of an n-gon is a function of just the points (an answer has just been posted to this effect).

Comment: @preferred_anon, I know this must be errata in the book, as stated below you could create different n-gons with the same points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

As I understand, the vertices are to be assumed to be entered in order otherwise there are multiple $n$-gons possible of different shapes, perimeters and areas with given set of data points.

Under this assumption, the sides will be uniquely determined by consecutive vertices.

The perimeter can be found by using Pythagoras theorem for $n$ side lengths.

The area can be found by using [Shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula#Statement).

Comment: Yes, I know that if you get them in order the problem is solved, but the textbook asks not to asume that the points will be entered in order.

Comment: @JocsanArielHernandezBarahon Then there will be multiple $n$-gons possible, arbitrarily many for large $n$. One can still try to calculate all possible perimeters and areas by Pythagoras and Shoelace. These will still be useful.

Comment: Precisely there will be $(n-1)!$ possible shapes. So for $n=6$, you're looking for $5!=120$ possible configurations of different shapes from a single data set, which doesn't seem interesting/practical (?)

Comment: Isn't it (n-2)! ? I can't think of how 3 points can give you 2 different triangles in $R^2$, however I think you're right and this must be some kind of errata in the book.

Comment: @JocsanArielHernandezBarahon It will be a positively (counterclockwise) and negatively (clockwise) oriented triangle out of same triangle shape. The shoelace formula will give area of same magnitude for two triangles but opposite in sign. It really is circular permutation if you think about it. You can correct it to $(n-1)!/2$, not $(n-2)!$.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I will talk it out with my professor, you''ve been of great help.